# Does regex in css conform to W3C standards?

Tags: css, regex, css-selectors, w3c

Not sure if this is a stack or not. Does it conform to W3C standards when I use regex in CSS expression? and can this work for all the web browsers?

```
<style type="text/css">
  a[class^='link']{color:#ccc;}
</style>
<a class="link-a">link A</a><br />
<a class="link-b">link B</a><br />
<a class="link-c">link C</a><br />
```

Comment: yes it is, look at  http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Comment: I don't understand your first sentence "Not sure if this is a stack or no."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- It is **standardized with CSS3**, even though support existed previously for this selector before CSS3 became a W3C Recommendation. Please see [w3c CSS3 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings).
- **Modern browsers and IE >=7 support it.** You can find it in the [Compatibility Charts of Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#CSS3).
- I have to note it **has nothing to do with Regex**, you cannot use regular expressions here. The operators (`^`, `$`) may be *borrowed* from Regex, but that's all.

Comment: +1 for the last bullet point, but I felt the need to state that the new attribute selectors entered the CSS3 drafts long before any browser supported them or IE7 was released. (CSS3 selectors just became a W3C Recommendation a couple of months ago.) This is unlike `word-wrap` or `overflow-x/y` which appeared as early as in IE5+ and were *then* standardized with CSS3.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks, history has never been my strong part :).

Comment: Yeah I find myself giving unsolicited history lessons about CSS once in a while. It's become one nasty habit!

Comment: @BoltClock I would not consider it a harmful habit. Keep spreading the knowledge :).